# app.config() not working while using ui.router in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, angular-ui-router

I am new to `AngularJs`. I got my first assignment and I'm having trouble adding the `ui.router` functionality in my app. I used it before and it worked but in this particular program it's not working. I used `console.log(test)` to check till where the code is being executed and it did not print anything under `.config`. What is wrong with it?

**main.js**:

```
var employeeNetworkApp = angular.module("myEmployeeUI",["ui.router"]);

employeeNetworkApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    console.log('test')
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider.state('/', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'partials/EmployeeUI.html'
    });
});
```

**index.html**:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "css/bootstrap-theme.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myEmployeeUI">
    <div ng-include="'partials/EmployeeUI.html'"></div>

    <div ui-view></div>

    <!--<div ng-include="'../partials/LaunchModalDemo.html'"></div>-->
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src ="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src = "controllers/employeeDatabase.controller.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/page.controller.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: When using ui-router you should also include a base tag in the head. I think that the config function should still be executed though, but it's worth a try. Pop this in to your head tag. <base href="/"></base>

Comment: taken from this page, just search 'base' and it's the 4th result.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions